# Help with RX 470 Miner Calculations

Tags: gpu-mining, mining-profitability

I am a few clicks away from purchasing everything to build a rig with the following specification.

3x Intel Celeron G1840 Processor
3x Asrock H81 Pro BTC motherboard
3x 6x AMD Radeon RX 470 8GB
3x 4GB DDR3 Memory
3x 60GB SDD Harddisk
3x 1000W Gold power supply
3x Windows 10 operating system
Power wattage 2150W

It should achieve around 450 MH/s (+- 5%)

I have been messing with some calculators trying to get an idea of how much XMR I could generate daily. I have been converting 450 mh/s into 450000 h/s but I think I am doing something wrong.

Can anyone advise me how much this rig could generate per day based on current reward and difficulty and network hash rate.

I just want to be sure on potential before committing to purchasing the hardware.

Really appreciate any help and advice given.

Regards Pearse

Answer (score 3):

Your math seems wrong. Each RX 470 will deliver up to 700 H/s. (700 H/s)(6 cards)(3 rigs) = 12600 H/s. Without any modification, these cards will probably get you between 500-550 H/s each.

According to [this site](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/xmr), you would make about $14.69 a day in Monero and pay $8.64 a day in electricity. This is assuming you pay 12 cents per kWh. This is for all three rigs, not each individually.

One clarification: mining the CryptoNight algorithm in Monero is very different than the SHA-256 algorithm in many other coins (like Bitcoin). The hash rates produced for each algorithm are very, very different, and you can not simply take the amount of hashes a card would perform with Bitcoin and convert that 1:1 to Monero hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us the exact model RX-470 you are looking at? The RX-470's have a wide range of mining hash rates. I agree however with @JustinEU4, your calculations are way off. You're not going to get 450MH/S with a 3xRig system no matter what you do.